# I'm trying to fix a Value error incase a user enters an alphabet

Tags: python, try-catch

I just made an intangible atm app. nothing fancy,  you basically create an acct with an amount and can also withdraw. I'm trying to fix a **Value error** incase a user enters an alphabet in the Tkinter textbook  instead of an integer.

I did the try catch statement but it still throws a Value error.

```
def get_selected_row(event):

     try:

        global selected_tuple
        index = list1.curselection()[0]
        selected_tuple= list1.get(index)
        e1.delete(0,END)
        e1.insert(END,selected_tuple[1])
        e2.delete(0,END)
        e2.insert(END,selected_tuple[2])
        e3.delete(0,END)
        e3.insert(END,selected_tuple[3])
        e4.delete(0,END)
        e4.insert(END,selected_tuple[4])

    except ValueError:
        pass
        

def acct_details ():

    global balance
    list1.delete(0,END)
    list1.insert(END,("Hello", acct_name.get()))
    list1.insert(END, ("your account number is ", acct_number.get()))
    list1.insert(END, ("and your balance is", balance))


def clear():

    list1.delete(0,END)
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e2.delete(0,END)
    e3.delete(0,END)



def withdraw_fxn(amount):

    list1.delete(0,END)
    try:
        global balance
        if balance < amount:
            list1.insert(END,('Sorry, you have an insufficient Balance'))
        else:
            balance = balance - amount
            list1.insert(END, (acct_name.get(), "Your new balance is ",balance))
    except ValueError:
        pass

    

def deposit_fxn(amount):

    list1.delete(0,END)
    global balance
    try:
        balance += amount
        list1.insert(END,(acct_name.get(), "your new balance is ", balance))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Value error. and I already made a try catch statement for the value error

Answer (score 0):

You are catching an IndexError, to catch a ValueError you must add

```
except ValueError:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching an Value error incase user enters an alphabet, you can try putting an if condition after wherever you input the details and using the `isalpha()` method, you can check if any alphabet is entered, if yes, you can tell the user that and not accept that input.